# Confused about a type of substitution I haven't seen before.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I saw this online and I'm confused as to what happened with the $\lambda$ substitution:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^x}&=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{e^{x\ln x}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^1dx(\underbrace{x\ln x}_y)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^n}{d\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^0dy\;e^{\lambda y}\Bigg|_{\lambda=n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^n}
\end{align*}$$

What is the thought process involved in getting to that point, and where does the derivative come in?

Comment: It looks like an attempt at "Feynman's trick", but I do not understand the change in limits of integration. If you set $y = x\ln x$, then $\lim_{x\to 0+} y = \lim_{x\to 1-} y = 0$. At no point on the interval does $y \to -\infty$.

Comment: I thought I'd at least answer your question about the derivative. $$\frac {d^n}{d\lambda^n} e^{\lambda y} = y^ne^{\lambda y}$$ The idea is that while $e^{\lambda y}$ is easily integrable, $y^ne^{\lambda y}$ is harder, so they exchange the order of differentiation and integration to integrate the simple version, and differentiate afterwards. Exchanging the order of limit operations is not always justifiable, so they should prove it is here, but this is often ignored. I don't see the rest of it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo, the substitution should be $x = e^y$ rather than $x\ln x = e^y$. Making this substitution gives

$$(x\ln x )^n\,dx = e^{ny}y^n d(e^y) = e^{(n+1)y}y^n\,dy$$

which is what you want for the next step. At this point you may use the trick as explained in the comments.

I don't necessarily think there is any special though process going on here, just that exponential is often easier to calculate with than logarithms.

By the way this equation is called Sophomore's dream and you can search more about it such as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).